# Symbol for close to but below

Tags: limits

Let’s say x=0.97 and I want to symbolically emphasize that X is below but close to 1. Is there a symbol that I can use which denotes that situation? Thanks.

Comment: We can write $x\approx 1 \land x<1$ but I guess it's kinda trivial.

Answer (score 4):

$\lesssim$ (MathJax/LaTeX: `\lesssim`) is sometimes seen meaning that.

Comment: That is what I thought of.  But define it the first time ... since I think it could also mean: "less than or slightly larger than"

Answer (score -1):

In the case of limits I have seen $lim_{x\to1^-}$, meaning that $x$ is approaching $1$ from below.